# Jquery read more read less function

Tags: jquery, slide

Im trying to make a read more, read less function.

The function seems to work, just not correctly.

The button from load says read more, but it doesnt show the shorter version to begin with.

THen when you click on button it changes all of the slides at once, when i only want the one to move when clicked.

Im sure its a easy fix but im a newbie to jquery so having trouble creating the easiest functions

Thanks

```
<div class="team-member">

<div class="image">
    <img width="120" height="120" />
</div>

<div class="text">
    <h3>Mr John Kuo <span>LLB</span></h3>
    <h4>Executive Director and Chief Operating Officer</h4>


<div class="more-less">    
    <div class="more-block">

    <p>Mr Kuo has more than 10 years’ experience in international import &amp; exporting, commodities trading, international business development and strategic alliance planning. Before Resources, he was the vice general manager for BAAO Mining which is a Chinese raw material trading company based in Tianjin, China.</p>

    <div class="full-text">
        <p>Mr Kuo has more than 10 years’ experience in international import &amp; exporting, commodities trading, international business development and strategic alliance planning. Before Resources, he was the vice general manager for BAAO Mining which is a Chinese raw material trading company based in Tianjin, China.</p>
 <p>Mr Kuo has more than 10 years’ experience in international import &amp; exporting, commodities trading, international business development and strategic alliance planning. Before Resources, he was the vice general manager for BAAO Mining which is a Chinese raw material trading company based in Tianjin, China.</p>
 <p>Mr Kuo has more than 10 years’ experience in international import &amp; exporting, commodities trading, international business development and strategic alliance planning. Before Resources, he was the vice general manager for BAAO Mining which is a Chinese raw material trading company based in Tianjin, China.</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>


        <div class="more-link">
        <a href="#"><span class="icon"></span><span class="text">View More</span></a>
                        </div>



                </div>

            </div>


            <div class="team-member">

                <div class="image">
                    <img width="120" height="120" />
                </div>

                <div class="text">
                    <h3>Mr. Bon Jun<span></span></h3>
                    <h4>Non-Executive Director</h4>


        <div class="more-less">    
            <div class="more-block">

                <p>Mr Li holds a Bachelor of Mechanical Engineering degree from the Beijing Architecture Engineering University. He has worked for one of the biggest state owned company which has imported plant and e company under Thyssen in Germany and then moved to  to work as the Managing Director of Golden Mall Enterprise until 1999.</p>

                                <div class="full-text">
                                    <p>Mr. Li has rich experience in connecting foreign companies with enterprises and ever been involved in more than big projects with success. At present Mr. Li is the Limited in Beijing providing consulting services to clients globally In recent years Mr. Li has assisted Australian resources companies in establishing relationship with customers in leading to a number of successful projects.</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="more-link">
                            <a href="#"><span class="icon"></span><span class="text">View More</span></a>
                        </div>



                </div>

            </div>
```

And here is the jquery

```
$(".team-member .more-link span.text").click(function(){
 var moreAndLess = $(".full-text").is(':visible') ? 'View More' : 'View Less';
$(this).text(moreAndLess);

 $(".full-text").slideToggle();
 });

 $(".team-member .more-link a").click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$('<div/>')
.append('default ' + event.type + ' prevented')
.appendTo('#log');
});
```

Heres the jfiddle of how it looks,

http://jsfiddle.net/strohy85/6pEfg/1/

---

I got a version working,, but its a bit buggy, if you press view more view less a few times, it shows the link that should be hidden not sure why.
http://jsfiddle.net/strohy85/6pEfg/8/

Comment: i got a version working,, but its a bit buggy, if you press view more view less a few times, it shows the link that should be hidden not sure why.
http://jsfiddle.net/strohy85/6pEfg/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, here is jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/strohy85/Hg7pD/3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.full-text').hide();

 $('.view-btn').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().find('.full-text').slideToggle('slow');
    $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Read less...' ? 'Read more...' : 'Read less...');
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

**Html**

```
<div class="team-member">

<div class="image">
    <img width="120" height="120" />
</div>

<div class="text">
    <h3>Mr John Kuo <span>LLB</span></h3>
    <h4>Executive Director and Chief Operating Officer</h4>


<div class="more-less">    
    <div class="more-block" >

    <p>Mr Kuo has more than 10 years’ experience in international import &amp; exporting, commodities trading, international business development and strategic alliance planning. Before Resources, he was the vice general manager for BAAO Mining which is a Chinese raw material trading company based in Tianjin, China.</p>

    <div class="full-text" style="display:none;">
        <p>Mr Kuo has more than 10 years’ experience in international import &amp; exporting, commodities trading, international business development and strategic alliance planning. Before Resources, he was the vice general manager for BAAO Mining which is a Chinese raw material trading company based in Tianjin, China.</p>
 <p>Mr Kuo has more than 10 years’ experience in international import &amp; exporting, commodities trading, international business development and strategic alliance planning. Before Resources, he was the vice general manager for BAAO Mining which is a Chinese raw material trading company based in Tianjin, China.</p>
 <p>Mr Kuo has more than 10 years’ experience in international import &amp; exporting, commodities trading, international business development and strategic alliance planning. Before Resources, he was the vice general manager for BAAO Mining which is a Chinese raw material trading company based in Tianjin, China.</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>


        <div class="more-link">
        <a href="#"><span class="icon"></span><span class="text">View More</span></a>
                        </div>



                </div>

            </div>


            <div class="team-member">

                <div class="image">
                    <img width="120" height="120" />
                </div>

                <div class="text">
                    <h3>Mr. Bon Jun<span></span></h3>
                    <h4>Non-Executive Director</h4>


        <div class="more-less">    
            <div class="more-block">

                <p>Mr Li holds a Bachelor of Mechanical Engineering degree from the Beijing Architecture Engineering University. He has worked for one of the biggest state owned company which has imported plant and e company under Thyssen in Germany and then moved to  to work as the Managing Director of Golden Mall Enterprise until 1999.</p>

                                <div class="full-text">
                                    <p>Mr. Li has rich experience in connecting foreign companies with enterprises and ever been involved in more than big projects with success. At present Mr. Li is the Limited in Beijing providing consulting services to clients globally In recent years Mr. Li has assisted Australian resources companies in establishing relationship with customers in leading to a number of successful projects.</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="more-link">
                            <a href="#"><span class="icon"></span><span class="text">View More</span></a>
                        </div>



                </div>

            </div>
```

and **Javascript**

```
<script>

        $(".team-member .more-link span.text").click(function(){
            //alert($(".full-text").attr('style'));
            var moreAndLess = ($(".full-text").attr('style') == "") ? 'View More' : 'View Less';
            $(this).text(moreAndLess);


             $(".full-text").slideToggle();
             });

             $(".team-member .more-link a").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('<div/>')
            .append('default ' + event.type + ' prevented')
            .appendTo('#log');

            });

        </script>
```

It will work as u expect.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.
This kinda works, it still triggers both to work at the same time tho. And the View More/View less state gets locked at View Less when you click after a few go's.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need something like this:

```
$(".team-member .more-link span.text").click(function () {
  var moreAndLess = $(this).text() == 'View More' ? 'View Less' : 'View More';
  $(this).text(moreAndLess);
  $(".full-text").slideToggle();
});
```

and your html little bit changed either style the `display:none` or make a css class and put the `display` property to `none`:

```
<div class="full-text" style='display:none;'>
```

in css class:

```
.full-text{
   display:none;
}
```

#### [Checkout the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6pEfg/4/)

Comment: This nearly works as well, just triggers both the slides to move at same time when only want the one to move..

Comment: `$(".full-text").prev('p').toggle();` this can be removed from the code. updated try this one.

Comment: it still seems to trigger both to slide when one is clicked
http://jsfiddle.net/strohy85/6pEfg/5/

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was able to replicate a portion of your question where in you would like a slide down animation for your divs.

Kindly see this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/XkMbA/) for more details.

The main jist of it is to have the jquery `animate()` function.

```
 $(this).prev().animate({
        height: '300'
    }, 500);
    $(this).text('Read Less');
```

Unfortunately, the `animate()` function has some limitation as it cannot animate to an element's `auto` css property. Thus having the code to animate to 300px.

Comment: Thanks for that, yeah that looks nice. My text height would never be the same as different people would have different lengths of text, so i wouldnt be able to set the height.

Comment: Alright! I'm sorry that you have a problem with height. I'll be looking for more ways on how to improve on it.

Comment: All good, i got a version working,, but its a bit buggy, if you press view more view less a few times, it shows the link that should be hidden not sure why.
http://jsfiddle.net/strohy85/6pEfg/8/